# How to return value in component react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to return a value out of a component. Basically what it needs to do is just not being displayed if its turned on `{false}`.

`firstfile.tsx`

```
export default (isDisplayedLoadingTitle: IProps) => (
  <Fragment>
    {isDisplayedLoadingTitle && (
    <ChartLoaderUI.ChartTitleContainer>
      <ChartLoaderUI.ChartTitle>
        <ChartLoaderUI.Title>{`Loading...`}</ChartLoaderUI.Title>
      </ChartLoaderUI.ChartTitle>
    </ChartLoaderUI.ChartTitleContainer>
    )}
    <ChartLoaderUI.Container className={'chart-loader'}>
      <Loader />
    </ChartLoaderUI.Container>
  </Fragment>
);
```

Having that and in another file

`secondfile.tsx`

```
<ChartLoader isDisplayedLoadingTitle={false}/>
```

How can I modify the returned value on `firstfile.tsx`?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the brackets to destructure that property from the object of properties, so currently you are using an object in your boolean comparison.

```
export default ({isDisplayedLoadingTitle}: IProps) => (
```

That will handle your bug of not pointing to the right key (aka it would always show because `{isDisplayedLoadingTitle: false} && (` will always be true

Comment: @DanielLogvin are you wanting to pass the display value from one component to the other?

Comment: Already did, I'm using an interface, the thing now is to modify css because it just gets sticked to the top of the page. Got any idea on how to modify the css inside that  `{isDisplayedLoadingTitle && (` ? Btw, thanks for the help, really appreciate it.

Comment: Well, you could not return a fragment as the top level element, rather an element you can use to style things. Some chart libraries give you the ability to style via props, you'd need to reference the docs for best practices there. If its props you know how to do that. if its just by override css classes then you can use a top level element to force those style overrides

Comment: Awesome, got it. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @DanielLogvin yep! If you have more questions feel free to reach out. when you are able to, please mark the answer as accepted so we can consider this question resolved! :) Happy coding!

Comment: Just marked it as resolved, I couldn't before because it gives an interval of 5 minutes to accept it since the answer is posted. I'll reach out (I'm sure I'll need a bit more of help haha), thanks again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198065/discussion-between-daniel-logvin-and-john-ruddell).

Comment: @DanielLogvin still not correct I replied if you want to read